# Getting variables from one method to another - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two methods/functions in my Codeigniter model

```
public function main_product($p_id) {


    $this->db->select('p.*');
    $this->db->from('products_main as p');
    $this->db->where('p.product_id',$p_id);
    $this->db->where('p.status','Active');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query->result();
        foreach($query->result() as $row):

            $product_tag = $row->product_tag;
            $product_id = $row->product_id;
            $name_family = $row->name_family;

        $this->main_images($product_id, $product_tag, $name_family);
        endforeach;         
    else:
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', 'The main product query was unsuccessful.' );
    endif;      
}


public function main_images($product_id, $product_tag, $name_family) {
    //run query
    $this->db->select('im.*'); 
    $this->db->from('images_main as im');
    $this->db->where('im.pro_img_id',$p_id);
    /*$this->db->where('im.img_tag',$product_tag);
    $this->db->where('im.img_family',$name_family);*/
    $this->db->order_by('img_order', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query->result();
    else:
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', 'The new image query was unsuccessful.' );
    endif;      

}
```

I am trying to get some of the data from the successful main_product function over to the main_images function.  I thought I could pass it through variables like I would in the model but it was unsuccessful.  After looking around I found a few examples of what might be similar to this but was also unsuccessful in making it work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `main_images` function, `$this->db->where('im.pro_img_id',$p_id);` should become `$this->db->where('im.pro_img_id',$product_id);` as `$p_id` is not defined.

Furthermore I would **strongly** suggest that you keep all database interaction in the model. The controller should only pass data from the model to the view, or from the user to the model.

Comment: I made the change but I have this error "Message: Missing argument 1 for Shop_model::main_images(), called in /application/controllers/mainpro.php on line 26 and defined"  This is the same for argument 2, and argument 3.  Also this is in a model sorry about the typo.

Comment: The error is thrown in the Mainpro controller. Check that file.

Comment: $this->shop_model->main_images() This line, which is the one its talking about, has no arguments but I thought because I was passing arguments in the model (as per the code above) that there would be no need for it in the controller?

Comment: Every time you call the `main_images` method you need to provide the arguments, regardless of *where* you call it.